# Replace missing values with calculated values

Tags: r, missing-data

I'm trying to learn how to replace missing data in one variable with calculated values.

My dataset (`bk3`) looks like:

```
ign:  80, 96, 75, 66, 53

Mean: 26, 24, 27, 34, 41

sd:    6,  7, NA,  8,  4

lci:  24, 25, 20, 32, 38

uci:  29, 26, 29, 33, 43
```

dput:

```
bk3 <- structure(list(ign = c(80L, 96L, 75L, 66L, 53L), mean = c(26L, 24L, 
  27L, 34L, 41L), sd = c(6L, 7L, NA, 8L, 4L), lci = c(24L, 25L, 20L,
  32L, 38L), uci = c(29L, 26L, 29L, 33L, 43L)), .Names = c("ign",
  "mean", "sd", "lci", "uci"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Basically, I'm using the 95% confidence intervals (`uci`, `lci`) and sample n's (`ign`) to calculate the missing SDs (`sd`).

The code I'm trying to use is:

```
bk3$sd[is.na(bk3$sd)] <- (bk3$uci - bk3$lci) * sqrt(bk3$ign)/3.92
```

But I'm getting the following warning message:

> "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"

Update: I'm trying to create a function that will do this automatically given the appropriate variables are provided. I've tried setting it up in the following format:

```
fillsd <- function(x, n, u, l)
{ 
i1 <- is.na(x)
i2 <- n > 59
x[i1 & i2] <- with(df, (u[i1 & i2] - l[i1 & i2]) * (sqrt(n[i1 & 
i2])/3.92)) }
```

While the function "fillsd" appears to have saved appropriately in my global environment, it doesn't work when I try use it with the following code:

```
fillsd(x="bk3$sd", n="bk3$ign", u="bk3$uci", l="bk3$lci")
```

No error message results from that code, but the function didn't appear to do anything either. This is the first function I've worked on, and I haven't been able to find comparable examples to know which part of the code is incorrect. Please let me know if you have any ideas about how to make this work. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this. This was the output using dput: structure(list(ign = c(80L, 96L, 75L, 66L, 53L), mean = c(26L, 
24L, 27L, 34L, 41L), sd = c(6L, 7L, NA, 8L, 4L), lci = c(24L, 
25L, 20L, 32L, 38L), uci = c(29L, 26L, 29L, 33L, 43L)), .Names = c("ign", 
"mean", "sd", "lci", "uci"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

Comment: It's okay.  I posted a solution below.  You can check whether that is what you wanted

Comment: Hi akrun, thank you again for your response to my question. I had forgotten that I only needed to complete that computation for ign values >59, and that there is a separate computation for ign values less than or equal to 60. I'm trying to replicate the STATA command "if ign>59". I've been looking everywhere for an analog, and I can't seem to find one as simple. I tried creating ifelse statements to no avail. Would you know how to do that? Thanks again.

Comment: Not completely clear about your problem.  Perhaps `i2 <- bk3$ign > 59` and then use this also as index i.e. `with(bk3, (ici[i1 & i2] - lci[i1 & i2] * sort(ign[i1 & i2])/3.92)`

Comment: Could you please update it in your post?  It is not clear from the comments

Comment: I think you need to change the parameters to the function.  You are passing quoted strings.  Instead, it should be without strings.  Also, after the assignment, it should return the column or dataset you wanted

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Could you clarify the second part - "after the assignment"? And I have tried to call the function without quotes around the variables, and unfortunately it runs, but the missing values remain missing.

Comment: What i meant is that the last line in the function is `x[i1 & i2] <- ..`.  After that, you may need `x}` if the intention is to return that column

Comment: Thank you again. That worked in terms of seeing the computed values. I was hoping the computed values would replace the NAs in the actual dataframe. I tried to create a new variable assigned to "x", but that didn't work. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we `replace` the NA elements of 'sd' with the corresponding elements of calculated values of other columns, then the logical index should be on both sides of the assignment.  Based on the nature of the calculation, it gives a length that equal to the number of rows of the dataset while the lhs is only having less length as we are subsetting only rows that have NA elements which leads to length inequality and thus the error

```
i1 <- is.na(bk3$sd)
bk3$sd[i1] <- with(bk3, (uci[i1] - lci[i1]) * sqrt(ign[i1])/3.92)
```

However, if we decide to get a summary based on taking the `mean` of `sum` of some columns, it is a single number and it would make sense to not have the logical index on the rhs as the value gets recycled

#### data

```
bk3 <- structure(list(ign = c(80, 96, 75, 66, 53), Mean = c(26, 24, 
27, 34, 41), sd = c(6, 7, NA, 8, 4), lci = c(24, 25, 20, 32, 
38), uci = c(29, 26, 29, 33, 43)), .Names = c("ign", "Mean", 
"sd", "lci", "uci"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```